# Left outer join with select where value in right table does not return all rows from left

Tags: mysql

I have a polymoprhic relationship table "likes" in which I store likes for the tables "lists", "articles", "comments".

The structure of the table is as follows:

- id
- content_id
- content_type

I am trying to select all my lists with their like counts:

```
SELECT lists.*, COUNT(DISTINCT likes.id) AS likes FROM lists
                                      LEFT OUTER JOIN likes ON (lists.id = likes.content_id)
                                      WHERE likes.content_type = 'list'
                                      GROUP BY lists.id
```

However, it only returns results from the list table where there are likes in the likes table.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need  left join you must inclue the where  condition in on clause otherwise i used  as inner join

```
SELECT lists.*, COUNT(DISTINCT likes.id) AS likes 
FROM lists
LEFT OUTER JOINlikes ON 
    (lists.id = likes.content_id 
          AND likes.content_type = 'list')  
GROUP BY lists.id
```